# Lowering of resistance

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electrical-resistance

Here's a doubt regarding of lowering of resistance. Can a body placed in a magnetic field can have its resistance to electric current decreased?? If yes which are those substances. Is there a specific name to such substances.

Can you also please explain the reason behind this phenomenon.

Comment: You are referring to magnetoresistance, see; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoresistance

Comment: Did you really mean *doubt*?

Comment: @AdrianHoward Thank you

Comment: @noah Yeah its a kind of doubt. I really dont know anything abt such substance. Iam still in my school, i know conductors, insulators, superconductors, semiconductors and few magnetic substances.

Comment: The "giant" version of that is very important in good old HDDs; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_magnetoresistance

Comment: @noah Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The body's electrical resistance, or more precisely its electrical impedance is, among other things, voltage dependent, being high at low voltage. Most of its impedance under dry or slightly moist conditions is in its skin, which can be modeled electrically as a parallel combination of a resistor and capacitor. Internally, it's modeled primarily as resistance. Any inductance would be negligible.

So it is unlikely that a  magnetic field would lower the body impedance to any significant extent. For what it's worth, in my 40+ years of experience in the area of electric shock, I have never encountered any discussion or research on the effects of magnetic fields on body impedance.

Hope this helps.